# How can take numbers from string?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a collection of these strings, it contains month & year & string

```
 arad  9/2020
 hyerr 7/2022
 dsght 10/2021
 .....
```

I want to take month & year then put `15` as day with each one

my code:

```
foreach($files as $file){

  $years = [2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026]; // in my file I just have these years
  $months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]; // of course these are months. 

  $month = "";
  $year = "";

  // how can I check here!

  // $file['expired_date'];

  $new_expired_date = "15-$month-$year";

}
```

Comment: What are you attempting to check? Currently you're overwriting `$new_expired_date` within the loop.

Comment: @aynber check each string if each one has any year & month like in my array then save it in `$month` & `$year` vars to make my new date then store in DB

Comment: Have a look at [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: what does `$files` contain?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto contains a collection of arrays each one has filed called `expired_date` that contains this  string that I want to filter the date from it!

Comment: @AramBecker Yeah but I did not get the idea how can I get the string from it!

Comment: Do you have only this format input data "some_text 12/2021" or your date anywhere in the text?

Comment: @PavloMezhevikin Yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the date portion of the string is a standard format and a fixed-length `... 00/0000`, you can grab the final 7 characters and explode them on the slash `/`. This will give you an array that you can combine with your date (15) into a final string.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/44ee4dad439fd72faca41ffb91f91d16cb9784d8

```
<?php

$input = [
    'arad  9/2020',
    'hyerr 7/2022',
    'dsght 10/2021',   
];

foreach ($input as $line) {
    $date = trim(substr($line, -7));
    
    list($month,  $year) = explode('/', $date);
    
    $newDate = vsprintf('%s-%s-%s', ['15', $month, $year]);
    
    echo $newDate . "\n";
}
```

Output

```
15-9-2020
15-7-2022
15-10-2021
```